# Privileged Identity Management for switch users' account

Tags: cisco, switch, aaa

Is it possible to create an account in the switch for managing switch users' accounts such like changing password but may not allow to change specific administrator user. Can it be set on lower privilege to do that?

Several attempts are in vain on the part of setting username in the executable command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Yes. It is possible. You need to use RADIUS or tacacs+ Server.

Its are centralized Authentication servers such as active directory. Radius server is available in windows Server environment as well.

Especially when you configure these setting,do not forget config second level authentication as well.

> Radius Server is less secure than TACACS+ server because of password
>   encryption method.

Additionally TACACS+ server contain below Features and capabilities.

- Separates all 3 elements of AAA, making it more flexible.
- More secure - Encrypts the whole packet including username, password, and attributes.
- Central management for authorization configuration
- Full command logging.
- Supported by most major vendors

Radius Server has following Features and capabilities

- Combines authentication & authorization
- Requires each network device to contain authorization configuration.
- Minimal vendor support for authorization
- Designed for subscriber AAA